# md-switch not appearing after deploying to test site

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

We have a website that made use of angular-material's `md-switch`. It worked just fine in our development environment (i.e. visible in page). However, after it was deployed in our test environment, the switch disappeared. Checking the browser's console did not return any errors regarding the libraries used.

When we inspected the elements, we saw this:

**Development Environment**
[image: Development env.]

Result:
[image]

**Testing Environment**
[image]

Result:
[image]

This is how we referenced our libraries. We used `localhost` to reduce script loading time:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/SitePages/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/SitePages/app/lib/angular/hammer.min_2.0.4.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/SitePages/app/lib/angular/angular-animate.min_1.5.5.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/SitePages/app/lib/angular/angular-aria.min_1.5.5.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/SitePages/app/lib/angular/angular-material.min_1.1.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/SitePages/app/assets/css/angular-material_1.1.1.css" />
```

Hope somebody can shed some light over this.

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look like the AM files are loaded. If you view the source does it show the AngularJS and AM files?

Comment: Hi @camden_kid yep. All of the libraries above were called. However, the `<styles>` for the `md-switch` weren't loaded. :(

Comment: Could you show us the part of the view source that shows the files are actually loaded? I'm pretty sure angular-material.js is not loaded.

Comment: After checking the other JS files involved, that turned out to be the case. `ngMaterial` for some reason was missing from the list of called dependencies. @@ Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the culprit... turned out that somewhere in the middle of deployment, `ngMaterial` didn't get included/was removed from the list of dependencies. Reason why we didn't notice it immediately was aside from the lack of errors, all of the dependencies were called from a different JS file (not the one that specifically handles the switch). Bringing it back did the trick. -facepalm-